# How to Drag Draggable from one DragTarget to another?

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

I have a draggable image in Drag Target, I can move it around but it is not accepted in another Drag Target, I am sure Drag Target returns true every time for willAccept(). How to handle this?

Issue: How to drag object from one DragTarget to other?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

The drag target now returns Draggable